# I'm trying to use the object oriented method in matplotlib to generate plots, but it doesn't display any plots or errors

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Here is my workflow for creating plots using object oriented approach in Jupyter Notebook:

[image: workflow example]

I have tried every possible solution to resolve it like

- restarting the kernel
- tried on a new notebook
- updating the environment
- updated the libraries that i am using
- also use the `plt.show()` and `plt.show(block=True)` but nothing works

If I am trying a functional method the graphs are displaying smoothly but not in object oriented method. How can i resolve this issue to get the graphs display?

Comment: Could you explain please what do you mean by _functional method_?

Comment: When using matplotlib we have two approaches:

1-pyplot interface / functional interface.
2-Object-Oriented interface (OO).
 So in (functional method /pyplot interface) All the pyplot commands make changes and modify the same figure. This is a state-based interface, where the state (i.e., the figure) is preserved through various function calls (i.e., the methods that modify the figure). This interface allows us to quickly and easily generate plots. The state-based nature of the interface allows us to add elements and/or modify the plot as we need, when we need it.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to plot a figure created in another cell:

- use `display(fig)` to draw the current state of a figure under the cell (if `display` is not available then import it like `from IPython.display import display`;
- put the name of a figure at the very last line, `display` will be called automatically, but in addition the figure will be stored in the `Out` dictionary of a notebook, which may be not desirable;
- connect `pyplot` with a figure and call the `show` method after that: `plt.figure(fig); plt.show()`.

Workflow example:

[image: workflow]

Comment: For the sake of completeness, additionally, `fig.figure` or `ax.figure` alone on the last line of a cell will allow redisplaying of the previously define plot figure by using the `.figure` attribute to call it and then relying on the special handling of the last expression in a Jupyter cell to trigger display of it. I made a gist of the code and plots in the answer and what I tagged on that can be viewed nicely in nbviewer [here](https://nbviewer.org/gist/fomightez/d0b5df5ea73eb0e1be743c61deda7251).