# Can I update an axes with additional plot in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I was trying to plot different types of plot on the same axes I am not getting the desired output when I try to plot in different cells of jupyter notebook. Where as when I try to do it in same cell I am getting different result. Can I update an axes with additional plot in jupyter notebook ?
Why don't I get the two plots on same axes?

[image]

I was expecting this

[image]

Comment: I think you mean you want to do this in different cells even though you show one in your expect? (I think you just meant to show the plot and not the code?) You should expect a plot object to be closed and gone when you run the cell. That is how modern Jupyter works. You need to assign it to keep it accessible later. ...

Comment: See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76842073/im-trying-to-use-the-object-oriented-method-in-matplotlib-to-generate-plots-bu#comment135475377_76842974) with [a demo notebook](https://nbviewer.org/gist/fomightez/d0b5df5ea73eb0e1be743c61deda7251) related to that post.  But that is for the entire figure and you just really need the plot to add to. The idea is similar but for a different object. You want to assign things to handles. I'm trying to find an example I can point you at.

Comment: Note that I could have done a reply to your actual question a lot easier if you supply the code and not just images. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), paying particular attention to the section 'Help others reproduce the problem' that emphasizes "code to allow others to reproduce the problem" and  "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—**". You can add images to illustrate something that, but you should always have the code that corresponds included as well.

Comment: I made a notebook with code as a starting point for discussing this. You can [view it here](https://nbviewer.org/gist/fomightez/a2224fe23d17944a5c601fbbe5c6dda5). (The actual gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/fomightez/a2224fe23d17944a5c601fbbe5c6dda5).) The top one seems closer to yours and so I'll try to adapt that one.

Comment: Your cell `ax.plot(X, fitvalue)` showed a 2D lines object because that was the object on the last line. **No complete plot figure object was built in that cell to display there.** And you didn't reinvoke the plot figure you made earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the handles applied to recall the specific axes object of the subplot and modify the content there. Then you need to recall the figure to redisplay it, which will be modified.

I made an example that supplies code [in a Jupyter notebook that you can view here](https://nbviewer.org/gist/fomightez/e92d4e1abf2657676cda84560d5d8f2b). The actual corresponding gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/fomightez/e92d4e1abf2657676cda84560d5d8f2b). (There is an expanded version with actual use of subplot to have two side-by-side plots [to view here](https://nbviewer.org/gist/fomightez/a2224fe23d17944a5c601fbbe5c6dda5). The actual corresponding gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/fomightez/a2224fe23d17944a5c601fbbe5c6dda5).)

I'll boil it down for here:

#### Cell 1 - a cell producing a scatter plot

```py
#based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/75562058/8508004 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/26447505/8508004
import numpy as np
x_data, y_data = np.repeat(np.linspace(0, 9, 100)[None,:], 2, axis=0) + np.random.rand(2, 100)*2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x_data, y_data);
```

Running that cell will display the scatter plot.

#### Cell 2 - Set up the regresion line data

```py
z = np.polyfit(x_data, y_data, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
```

Nothing is output from that cell.

#### Cell 3 - add a regression line to the scatter plot and display the plot now with the regression line

```py
ax.plot(x_data,p(x_data), '-', color= "orange")
fig
```

Running that cell next will display the scatterplot that now has the regression line added.

A couple notes on that:

- Note that the code I present for being cell #2 doesn't actually need to be cell #2. The content there just needs to be executed somewhere before the code in the next cell. Cell #3 is kept short  given the OP has a cell with only `ax.plot()` on a single line in a cell all by itself, and so I wanted to have the final part be closer to that situation.
- `fig` doesn't necessarily need to be in the same cell with the command to add the trend line. It can be run later to display the modified plot figure. Additionally instead of just `fig` on the last line of the cell, you can use `display(fig)` earlier in a cell and have something else as the last line.

  For example **cell #3** could be reworked as a single line like the OP had:

  ```py
  ax.plot(x_data,p(x_data), '-', color= "orange");
  ```

  With the following as the next cell, **cell #4, to display the modified plot**:

  ```py
  display(fig)
  print("test")
  ```

  Or combine all that into an **alternative cell #3** to demonstrate re-invoking the plot figure after modification while showing it doesn't need to be invoked to display on the last line:

  ```py
  ax.plot(x_data,p(x_data), '-', color= "orange")
  display(fig)
  print("test")
  ```